# How to mock stompest send, and connect methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, stomp

I am writing a log handler for `ActiveMQ`. I have one class, `Messenger`, to publish a message to `ActiveMQ`. Also, I added class `Handler` to handle this and `get_logger` to get this logger.

```
import json
import logging

from stompest.config import StompConfig
from stompest.sync import Stomp

class Messanger(object):
    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.cfg = StompConfig(uri)

    def publish(self, queue, data):
        data = json.dumps(data)
        client = Stomp(self.cfg)
        client.connect()

        try:
            client.send(queue, data)
        except Exception, exc:
            print "Error: ", exc
        client.disconnect()

class Handler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, amq_uri, out_queue):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.uri = uri

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        messanger = Messanger(self.uri)
        messanger.send(self.queue, msg)



def get_logger(uri, queue):
    logger = logging.getLogger('testlogger')
    logger.addHandler(Handler(uri, queue))

    return logger
```

I have written a UT for this.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch, Mock

from my_package import get_logger 

class TestHandler(TestCase):
    @patch('stompest.sync.client.Stomp')
    def test_activemq_handler(self, mock_stomp):
        URI = "tcp://localhost:61613"
        QUEUE = "/queue/logger_queue"

        mock_stomp.connect = Mock(return_value=1)
        mock_stomp.send = Mock(return_value=2)

        data = "This is test logging"

        LOG = get_logger(URI, QUEUE)
        LOG.error(data)
```

But still it goes to the original send method and tries to connect to the server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "./my_package/tests/test_activemq_handler.py", line 23, in test_activemq_handler
    LOG.error(data)
  File "/System/Library/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1191, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1284, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1294, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1334, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 757, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "./my_package/__init__.py", line 28, in emit
    messanger.send(self.queue, msg)
  File "./my_package/clients/stomp_messanger.py", line 41, in send
    client.connect()
  File "./my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stompest/sync/client.py", line 85, in connect
    for (broker, connectDelay) in self._failover:
  File "./my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stompest/protocol/failover.py", line 48, in __iter__
    yield broker, self._delay()
  File "./my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stompest/protocol/failover.py", line 66, in _delay
    raise StompConnectTimeout('Reconnect timeout: %d attempts' % self._maxReconnectAttempts)
StompConnectTimeout: Reconnect timeout: 0 attempts
```

How can I mock this?

Answer (score 0):

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

You are adding the patch to the wrong place. The `Messenger` class module imports `Stomp` from `stompest.sync` before the tests run, and that's why your patching has no effect. You should patch the reference to `Stomp` in your module.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch, Mock

from my_package import get_logger 

class TestHandler(TestCase):
    @patch('path.to.your.Messenger_class_module.Stomp') #path to your module
    def test_activemq_handler(self, mock_stomp):
        URI = "tcp://localhost:61613"
        QUEUE = "/queue/logger_queue"

        ...
```

[This](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) will help if you need further clarification on why this is happening.